# jQuery counter fails to show the correct value after animation

Tags: jquery, animation, count

I have a jQuery counter that updates every time a radio button is being checked, adding its value to the equation. So far so good. But as soon as a radio button with a high value is being checked, the counter animation fails to show the correct numbers. It will show for example 999 998 instead of 1 000 000 and so on. Here's the script:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    var total_span = 0;
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
     total_span += this.checked && +this.value; 
    });
    $({counter: +$('#total').text()}).animate({counter: total_span},{
     duration: 1000,
     easing: 'swing',
     step: function () {
       $('#total').text(Math.floor(this.counter));
       $('#total-2').text(Math.floor(this.counter));
     }
   }); 
  });   
});
```

Do anyone of you have a solution to this problem? Would be so grateful if anyone could help me :)

EDIT: You can see the problem in action here:
http://moodboy.se/radiobuttons/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function is design to deal with css animations. It works by '*tweening'* between two elements using a timer. The result will be different depending on the size of the tween.

This lack of precision means, when using numbers, accuracy cannot be guaranteed. One solution is to use the `complete` callback property of the animation function to apply the correct value on completion.

`.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    var total_span = 0;
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
     total_span += this.checked && +this.value; 
    });
    $({counter: + $('#total').text()}).animate({counter: total_span},{
     duration: 1000,
     easing: 'swing',
     step: function () {
       $('#total').text(Math.floor(this.counter));
       $('#total-2').text(Math.floor(this.counter));
     },
     complete : function(){
       $('#total').text(total_span);
     }
   }); 
  });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="togglelinks">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="toggle" href="#panel-one">Choices 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="toggle" href="#panel-two">Choices 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="toggle" href="#show-all" id="demo">Results</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span id="total">974996</span>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="panel-one" class="info-panel">
  <h1>Choices 1</h1>
  <label><input id="1001" name="choices-1" value="1195000" type="radio">1195000</label>
  <label><input id="1002" name="choices-1" value="925000" type="radio">925000</label>
  <label><input id="1003" name="choices-1" value="1275000" type="radio">1275000</label>
  <label><input id="1004" name="choices-1" value="1195000" type="radio">1195000</label>
  <label><input id="1005" name="choices-1" value="1195000" type="radio">1195000</label>
  <label><input id="1006" name="choices-1" value="1295000" type="radio">1295000</label>
  <p>
    <label><input id="2001" name="choices-1" value="1250000" type="radio">1250000</label>
    <label><input id="2002" name="choices-1" value="975000" type="radio">975000</label>
    <label><input id="2003" name="choices-1" value="1295000" type="radio">1295000</label>
    <label><input id="2004" name="choices-1" value="1250000" type="radio">1250000</label>
    <label><input id="2005" name="choices-1" value="1250000" type="radio">1250000</label>
    <label><input id="2006" name="choices-1" value="1345000" type="radio">1345000</label>
  </p>
  <a class="toggle" href="#panel-two">&gt; Choices 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh okey, I wasn't aware of that. With the complete function it seem to work just perfect, thank you so much for your complete answer :)